# Pandas merge and keep right and delete left

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have a price list of all securities on Friday. some the securities keep the same price on Saturday as Friday. I want to copy the prices of Friday to Saturday for the security prices listed not on Saturday.

I tried to do this task by using pandas `merge` as follows.

I do `outer` Join for the two data frames as follows with setting `Indicator` as `True`.

```
# df_friday has 10 securities
# df _saturday has 3 securities
merge_df=pd.merge(df_friday,df_saturday,on='security',how="outer",indicator=True)

merge_df = merge_df[merge_df['_merge']=='left_only']
merge_df =merge_df.drop(['price_y','_merge'],axis=1)
merge_df = merge_df.rename(columns = {'price_x':'price'})

df_saturday = pd.concat([df_saturday,merge_df],ignore_index=True)
```

My columns of the two data frames are the same,

```
Columns: [security, price]
```

Did I do it correct way? Or Could I do that in a simple way?

For Example,

```
# df_friday
  security price
1 apple    35.25
2 reliance  25.5
3 samsung   12.5
4 tata      28.5
5 sony      30.2

# df_saturday
  security price
1 reliance  26.8
2 samsung   11.2

# df_saturday_result should be as follows,
  security price
1 reliance  26.8
2 samsung   11.2
3 apple    35.25
4 tata      28.5
5 sony      30.2
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to question with expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some timing checks on the 3 methods mentioned in the other answers.

```
fri =pd.DataFrame (columns =['security', 'price'], index = range(3), data =[['a',2],['b',4],['c',6]] )
sat =pd.DataFrame (columns =['security', 'price'], index = range(2), data =[['a',3],['c',5]] )
```

```py
In [90]: %timeit out = sat.merge(fri, how='outer', on=['security', 'price']).drop_duplicates()
5.19 ms ± 150 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [91]: %timeit result_1 = pd.concat([sat,fri],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset=['security'], keep='first')
1.82 ms ± 26.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [92]: %timeit result_2 = pd.concat([sat, fri[~fri.security.isin(sat.security)]], ignore_index=True)
1.19 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [93]: %timeit out = sat.merge(fri, how='outer', on=['security', 'price']).drop_duplicates()
5.02 ms ± 181 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

It looks like filtering then concatenating is the fastest, while concat then dedup isn't too far bad. The merge is pretty slow in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do

```
df_saturday = df_saturday.merge(df_friday, how='outer', on=['security','price']).drop_duplicates(['security'], keep='first')

print(df_saturday)
```

Output:

```
   price    security                                                                                                                    
0  26.80  reliance                                                                                                                    
1  11.20   samsung                                                                                                                    
2  35.25     apple                                                                                                                    
5  28.50      tata                                                                                                                    
6  30.20      sony
```

Comment: Does a pandas merge respect the order? i.e. would `df_saturday`'s elements occur first?

Comment: Yup it keeps the order. `df_saturday` elements would come first and then `df_friday`

Comment: You could use keep='first' in the drop_duplicates() to make it explicit. Of course, default is keep='first', but specifying it would improve the readability .

Comment: @AsishM. Thank you for the question. I also had that question in my mind. That's why I used that method I mentioned in that question.

Comment: @Akshay and RebornCodeLover: Thank you. I didn't aware of the property keep.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use pandas.concat():

CODE:

```
import pandas as pd

fri =pd.DataFrame (columns =['security', 'price'], index = range(3), data =[['a',2],['b',4],['c',6]] )
sat =pd.DataFrame (columns =['security', 'price'], index = range(2), data =[['a',3],['c',5]] )
print ('TEST DATA:')
print (fri)
print (sat)

print ('\nSOLUTION 1: concatenate and eliminate duplicates')
result_1 = pd.concat([sat,fri],ignore_index=True).drop_duplicates(subset=['security'], keep='first')
print (result_1)

print ('\nSOLUTION 2: filter unique and then concatenate')
fri_unique = fri[~fri.security.isin(sat.security)]
result_2 = pd.concat([sat, fri_unique], ignore_index=True)
print (result_2)
```

## OUTPUT:

```
TEST DATA:
  security  price
0        a      2
1        b      4
2        c      6
  security  price
0        a      3
1        c      5

SOLUTION 1: concatenate and eliminate duplicates
  security  price
0        a      3
1        c      5
3        b      4

SOLUTION 2: filter unique and then concatenate
  security  price
0        a      3
1        c      5
2        b      4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So concat and outer merge do the same thing. Am I right?

Comment: Both ways should give same result. Choose whatever is faster and more readable in your context. There is often more than 1 way in Python.